# Trying to assign value in gridview cell in vb .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have a page where gridview value is bind while updating, i need to take value from one of the cell and fill it in another cell of gridview after multiplying it with some value on TextChanged of a textbox.
value is read from gridview label but not able to reassign in that 'lblPremium' cell

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblSharePercentage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SharePercentage")%>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblPremium" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NetPremium")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

on text change event of txtTotalPremium

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTotalPremium" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total Premium" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="UpdateToatlPremium" />
```

taking value from grid cell on text changed event

```
Protected Sub UpdateToatlPremium(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTotalPremium.TextChanged

For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.grdCoInsurance.Rows
  Dim lblSharePercentage = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblSharePercentage"), Label)
  Dim text As String = lblSharePercentage.Text
  Dim lblPremium = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblPremium"), Label)
  lblPremium.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(lblSharePercentage.Text) * CDec(txtTotalPremium.Text)) / 100
 DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblPremium"), Label).Text = lblPremium.Text
Next
End Sub
```

while checking on grid value of `lblPremium` cell is not updating.
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Gee, that should work. Is it possible that the grid is inside of a update panel, but the text box you enter data (with the  post back) is outside of the update panel? If yes, then move  the text box to inside the same update panel as the gridview

Comment: I will suggest to use client side update rather than server side for such calculation. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457475/how-to-get-gridview-cell-value-iterating-with-js-or-jquery) for client side scripting.

Comment: Is the textbox of Total Premium, outside the gridview? Please specify.